# How to negate this statement?

Tags: logic

I am to negate this statement ( P and Q ). I am thinking on it for a while and came up with (not P and not Q). But this is wrong answer as per my textbook. I am confused about this? Please help

Thanks

Comment: (not P or not Q) See [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA How is this?

Comment: Proving it; or checking it by truth table.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I have not reached upto truth tables. Is their way to do without them

Comment: For (P and Q) to be false, we'd need either P to be false, or Q to be false. So, either (not P) is true or (not Q) is true, that is, (not P or not Q) is true.

Comment: As an example, say when is the statement "I am a happy mathematician" not true? Well, I am not a mathematician or I am not happy right now...

Comment: @AlexVong can't it be i am not happy and i am not a mathematician

Comment: As for the question "*Is their way [sic] to do without them*" yes... if you click the link to the wikipedia page provided by Mauro ALLEGRANZA in the first comment there are **several** proofs.  If someone provides a link, it is usually for a reason and you should learn what you can from clicking the link before asking questions that the link already answers.

Comment: @J.Deff I have fixed it!

Comment: @JMoravitz i am asking for justification rather proof\

Comment: @AlexVong pray continue

Comment: What do you consider the difference between justification and proof?  Those words are practically synonymous to me.  You justify something by proving it and if you have proven something you have justified it.

Comment: As for "*can't it be i am not happy and i am not a mathematician*" although simultaneously being unhappy and not a mathematician will indeed make the statement "I am a happy mathematician" false, you are ignoring the fact that there are unhappy mathematicians and there are happy farmers who will think both the "I am unhappy and not a mathematician" and "I am a happy mathematician" phrases are false.  Implication is not the same as equivalence.  The book asked for an *equivalent* logical statement to the negation, not just a logical statement which implies the negation.

Comment: @JMoravitz i don't get your point about farmers

Comment: I think JMoravitz means the example has an ambiguity, it would be better to pick another example.

Comment: My point about the farmers, and the point that this whole exercise is trying to get across, is that the negation of a statement $P(x)$, what we write as $\neg P(x)$ should be such that $\neg P(x)$ is true for **all** $x$ that were false for $P(x)$, and should be false for **all** $x$ that were true for $P(x)$.  There shouldn't be any $x$ that are true for both $P(x)$ and $\neg P(x)$ simultaneously just as there shouldn't be any $x$ that are false for both $P(x)$ and $\neg P(x)$ simultaneously.  Happy farmers think both "I am happy mathematician" and "I am not happy and not mathematician" false

Comment: @JMoravitz As far as i can understand you you mean if P(x) = I am happy and i am a mathematician and ( not P(x) )= i am not happy and i am not a mathematician. then Happy farmers is the value of "$x$ " which not satisfies both the above.

Comment: @JMoravitz You mean to say that happy farmers forms a counter example to as to how P(x) and Negation P(x) is defined by me

Comment: happy farmers is an example of a value of $x$ which satisfies *neither* of the above, which again shouldn't happen implying something is wrong about your negation.  Look at another example, one using real numbers.  $(x\geq 1$ and $x\leq 3)$.  All numbers which make that statement true are in the range between $1$ and $3$ and all numbers which make it false are smaller than $1$ or larger than $3$.  The negation is not $x<1$ and $x>3$.  There are no numbers which are simultaneously bigger and smaller than $1$.  We want the negation to be true for $x=0$ and $x=4$ for example, so $x<1$ or $x>3$

Comment: @JMoravitz okey i have understood it it seems. If negation as defined me is true then we would not have " happy farmers" satisfying both statement and negation. But it seems we have " happy farmers" so there must be some error in negation. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

The statement $P$ and $Q$ is true when and only when both are true, so not $(P$ and $Q)$ should be true when either one or both is false.  You therefore want not $P$ or not $Q$.  Try it with a truth table and see.
$$\begin {array} {c|c| c| c} P&Q&\lnot(P\wedge Q)& \lnot P \vee \lnot Q\\ \hline
T&T&F&F\\T&F&T&T\\F&T&T&T\\F&F&T&T \end {array}$$
As others have said, this is one of DeMorgan's laws.

Answer (score 1):

[De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)'s laws define these inference rules:

1. $\neg(a \vee b) \equiv (\neg a \wedge \neg b)$
2. $\neg(a \wedge b) \equiv (\neg a \vee \neg b)$

Answer (score 0):

The negation of two statements being true at the same time is that at least one of them must be false. So not P or not Q.

Comment: Can't they be both false at same time

Comment: @J.Deff the "or" means that either one of them is true, or both. So the statement "not P or not Q" means that one of the following could hold: P is false, Q is false, or P and Q are false.

Comment: @J.Deff when you want to express that one must be false and the other one true, you use XOR